# How to return a View Controller through a protocol

Tags: swift, xcode, protocols, swift5

The problem is that I need to call a function of root class inside the class of custom table view. That function changes a text in the main view. I need to refresh that text very frequently, that is why I decided to override reloadData method to add some functionality there.

I am overriding reloadData method.

```
protocol ReloadingDelegate {
    func returnHomeController() -> HomeController
}

class EntriesTableVIew: UITableView {

    var reload: ReloadingDelegate?

    override func reloadData() {
        super.reloadData()
        print("reloaded")

        let homeController = reload?.returnHomeController()
        homeController?.reloadBalance()
    }
}
```

I am trying to use protocol in HomeCotroller to pass itself.

```
extension HomeController: ReloadingDelegate {

    func returnHomeController() -> HomeController {
        return self
    }

}
```

I am sure I am doing something wrong, since I do not fully understand the concept of protocols. So, the main issue in a nutshell: how can I call a function from one class inside another class; nevertheless, that function, when called straightforwardly from an instance of the class returns nil?
Thank you beforehand!

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you take a look for closures, but protocol/delegate can do it too.
in your classe you forgot to mention that you are are the " delegate " 
in viewdidload of HomeController should declare that reload.delegate = self

Answer (score 0):

You can pass directly your 'viewController' to 'EntriesTableVIew' and then call the method you want inside 'reloadData', ps:

```
class EntriesTableVIew: UITableView {

   var homeController: HomeController?

   override func reloadData() {
       super.reloadData()
       print("reloaded")

       homeController?.updateLabel()
   }

   deinit {
       homeController = nil
   } 
}

class HomeController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
    } 

    func updateLabel() {
       print("Update label here")
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, homeController is returns nil, so all the functionality is not executed(

Comment: Did you assigned 'HomeController' too  'entriesTableVIew' ?  You need to do it like this: 'entriesTableVIew.homeController = self'